# CreateInstanceLic is failing on Windows Server 2016 but not on Windows Server 2019

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-server

I have a console application that crashes on Windows Server 2016 at the `CreateInstanceLic()` API. But the same application is running fine on Windows Server 2019.

Comment: please show a [mre]

Answer (score -1):

My first guess would be that you have a valid license for the Windows Server 2019 and not for the Windows Server 2016. The failing call tries to aquire a valid license and this fails for 2016 but not for 2019.